# Can we move Report Folders from Sandbox to Production

Tags: reporting, deployment, reports-folder

I have created few folders in Sandbox and i would like to move them to production...Please suggest

Also i tried to modify existing folders in production...but couldn't even though i am system admin.

Comment: Were the folders you couldn't modify the standard ones or custom ones?

Comment: Standard folders

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar Check whether you have necessary permissions. Go to your profile. Under system permission find dashboard related permissions in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to deploy report folder either using:

1. [Changesets](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/app_deployment/app_deployment_changesets?id=app_deployment)
2. [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_deploying_ant.htm) or eclipse
3. [Workbench](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/alm_deployment/alm_tools?id=alm_deployment): From menu, Migrate -> Deploy

Check if you have appropriate [folder permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_folders.htm&language=en&type=0) to edit folders.

Comment: But i am not able to edit existing Report Folders & Hide it from all users ..Any suggestions on that

Comment: Refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008kNTIAY) link, you cannot edit existing folder!

Comment: Thats what i am trying to do...I am not deleting them..I am just trying to Hide them from users..

Comment: FYI ..I was able to modify those standard report folders in sandbox but not able to do the same in production..Any Idea why?

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar Most likely it has to do with the sharing that exists on your production folders. You'd need to remove all the sharing first, make your changes, then restore the sharing. The sharing likely doesn't exist on folders in your sandbox.